# How to install curl on windows for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, libcurl, feedzirra

I am new to ruby on rails.

Could you please help me to install curl. I have windows 7 and ruby 1.8.7

I need to install Paul Dix's FeedZirra. I need curl for that.

Also could you help me with gem install curb.

Even curb seems to need Curl

Looking forward for your help

Thank You

Gautam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download cURL for Windows at [cURL download page - Win32 section](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win32). The ZIP-file contains a curl.exe that you can run.

Comment: I did run. But I dont know what to do next. Now i install with gem install curb but i still no success. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: Please elaborate on "still no success"? What is the problem you're seeing? Does installation not succeed? Does it seem to install, but not work in actual use?